# Callback queue in case of synchronous callback

Tags: javascript

I understand that the asynchronous callback function will be pushed into the callback queue.
For eg:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('Async');
}, 0);
```

In the above case, the callback function is pushed into the callback queue.

Will the synchronous callback function will also be pushed into the callback queue?

```js
function a(b)
{
 console.log('First function')
}

a(function b()
{
console.log('Sync Callback')
});
```

will the function b will also be pushed into the callback queue?

Comment: No, a callback is just a function.  Ps, it's not a callback queue, it's an event loop.

Comment: I don't think setTimeout is async http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=c2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsKICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ0FzeW5jJyk7Cn0sIDApOwoKZnVuY3Rpb24gYShiKQp7CiBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygnRmlyc3QgZnVuY3Rpb24nKQp9CgphKGZ1bmN0aW9uIGIoKQp7CmNvbnNvbGUubG9nKCdTeW5jIENhbGxiYWNrJykKfSk7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D

Comment: @Keith those are different things. There is a callback queue (although its a task queue). The event loop pops items off the queue and runs them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox. What makes you think that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox you're right. It's not. JS is single threaded, the only way to get true asynchronous operations is to utilize different processes, or delegate the work to the environment through IO operations.

Comment: @Olian04. It wasn't the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @Keith good, because it wasn't true.

Comment: @Olian04 What's not true.?   It's the event loop in JS that makes things async, are you saying it's not?

Comment: @Keith I'm saying that leaving it at that is a gross understatement, and will lead to misunderstandings. While the event loop is a major part of JS, and in turn allows for async operations. The event loop it self is NOT asynchronous, and can NOT execute code in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: @Olian04  I maybe didn't make my point above obvious, but what I was trying to explain is that, NO: that function does NOT go into the event loop.   The fact that the event loop uses tasks queues / micro tasks etc is an implementation detail.  The main point is how the code was run, and again NO it's not run async, because it's not pushed on the event queue, wherever that be by magic pixies, or some queue the JS engine implements.  The over simplification was very deliberate, and I stand by it..

Comment: @Keith I can see that we're clearly on the same page and that neither of us are trying to mislead, we're simply using different levels of abstractions in our arguments. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will function `b` also be pushed onto the callback queue?

Short answer: NO.

Slightly longer answer: In your second snippet you are passing function `b` as an argument to function `a`, this happens synchronously. However you're never using function `b` inside function `a`, so while function `a` will evaluate, function `b` will neither be put on the queue, nor evaluated.

If you wanted `b` to be evaluated emediatly you would need to call it inside of `a`:

```js
function a(arg_b) {
  arg_b();
  console.log('First function')
}

a(function b() {
  console.log('Sync Callback')
});
```

If you instead wanted `b` to be put on the queue and evaluated at a later point, you would need to create a task (or a microtask):

```js
function a(arg_b) {
  setTimeout(arg_b, 0);
  console.log('First function')
}

a(function b() {
  console.log('Sync Callback')
});
```